# Find and replace in text file with terminal. How to escape all the characters?

Tags: macos, command-line, sed, terminal

I'm trying to use the terminal to replace some html code in a file.

This is the command I'm using

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/find/replace/g;' /Volumes/Abc.html
```

I'm trying to replace

```
<body>
```

with

```
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;page-break-after:always;padding-top:0%;">
<img src="images/image-001.jpg" id="illustration" alt="illustration" />
<div id="caption" style="text-align:right;font-style:italic;"></div>
</div>
```

so I've been trying this, but I can't figure out how to escape all the characters. Can you help?

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/<body>/<body>
<div style="text-align: center;page-break-after:always;padding-top:0%;">
<img src="images/image-001.jpg" id="illustration" alt="illustration" />
<div id="caption" style="text-align:right;font-style:italic;"></div>
</div>
/g;' /Volumes/Abc.html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use another separator, like `{}`.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's{<body>}{...}g' /Volumes/Abc.html
```

Comment: same here, couldn't get `sed` to work, this works fine. Now to figure out why ;)

Comment: +1000, cannot understand why I was trying to use sed all this time. Especially useful when changing multiple files: `perl -p ... 's{old}{new}g' *.html`... thanks!